# Como configurar o VSCode para identificar a sintaxe de campos privados

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou testando novos recursos do JS, mas meu VSCode não consegue detectar que o projeto utiliza a nova sintaxe de campos privados. O código está assim:

**entities.js**

```js
class Person {
    constructor(p = {}) {
        if(p) Object.assign(this, p)
    }

    #id
    get id() { return this.#id }
    set id(v) { this.#id = v }

    #name
    get name() { return this.#name }
    set name(v) { this.#name = v }

    #age
    get age() { return this.#age }
    set age(v) { this.#age = v}
}
```

Com base na documentação, ao utilizar esse código eu consigo criar uma classe que:

- Permite a passagem das propriedades como valores iniciais
- Permite que eu tenha campos ocultos (os campos iniciando com jogo da velha)
- Possibilita o encapsulamento das propriedades
- Possibilita o trabalho com OO de forma mais coerente e limpa.

Para eu trabalhar sobre o código eu estou usando o VSCode só que o mesmo não consegue ler essa forma de escrita e fica me informando que o código está incorreto:

[image: erro no VSCode que não consegue entender a linguagem]

O que preciso fazer para que o mesmo consiga entender o que estou escrevendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code atualmente não da suporte ao ES7 e o que eles sugerem na própria documentação oficial é desabilitar o validador nativo do JS e usar alguma extensão como o ESLint para validar o código. https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_how-do-i-disable-syntax-validation-when-using-nones6-constructs

> Some users want to use syntax constructs like the proposed pipeline (`|>`) operator. However, these are currently not supported by VS Code's JavaScript language service and are flagged as errors. For users who still want to use these future features, we provide the `javascript.validate.enable` setting.

***Traduzindo:*** *"Alguns usuários desejam usar construções de sintaxe como o operador de pipeline proposto (`|>`). No entanto, atualmente, eles não são suportados pelo serviço de linguagem JavaScript do VS Code e são sinalizados como erros. Para usuários que ainda desejam usar esses recursos futuros, fornecemos a configuração `javascript.validate.enable`."*

Com `javascript.validate.enable: false`, você desativa todas as verificações de sintaxe internas. Se você fizer isso, recomendamos usar um *linter* como o **ESLint** para validar seu código-fonte. Como o suporte a JavaScript do VS Code não entende as construções do ES7, recursos como o *IntelliSense* podem não ser totalmente precisos.

**ESLint**: https://eslint.org/

Marketplace do VS Conde com extensões que podem te ajudar: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=eslint&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance